# How to use Laravel 5 with Gulp, Elixir and Bower?

Tags: gruntjs, laravel-5, gulp, bower, laravel-elixir

I am completely new to all this, 'Bower' and 'Gulp' and Laravel 'Elixir'.  I purchased a template that uses them (unfortunately) and now I need some help on how to go about implementing them.  I have already installed NPM and Bower.  All my packages have been downloaded into:

```
resources > assets > vendor
```

This is a screenshot:

[image]

Now my question is how do I include all those packages I downloaded in my view? From my understanding I can't run less files directly in the browser, it only runs once due to 'browser caching' or something like that, also the JS scripts are just too many to include in my page.

I want a way where I can work on my files and have them automatically compiled with the compiled files being referenced in my app.php file.

This is a link to the GulpJS file included in my template: http://pastebin.com/3PSN6NZY

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to compile every time someone visits. The compiled sass/js should be run in dev and then the output files referenced.

If you have gulp installed on the project, you should see a gulp.js file in the root of your project. If not, visit here for instructions:

[Gulp/Elixer installation and setup](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/elixir#installation)

In your gulp.js file:

```
var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');

elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.less([
    'app.less',
    'normalize.less',
    'some-other-less.less',
    'and-another.less'
]);


mix.scripts(['app.js', 'some-other-js.js'], 'public/js/output-file.js');


});
```

While in development you can run `gulp watch` from the command line to listen for changes and run compile tasks when it hears a change. Then you simply reference the output files in the public directory as you normally would.

If you don't want to listen, you can just run the `gulp` command for a single once-off task run.

The docs are pretty straight forward and can be found here:

[Gulp/Elixer docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/elixir#usage)

Comment: Thank you very much, this has been very confusing for me, right now my real challenge is what to do with the gruntjs file that came with the template, there seems to be a lot of code in it, where do i place it?  The code seems different than what the laravel-elixir created.

Comment: I am so confused about how to mix and compile all the files in my assets/vendor folder.  The docs and videos i have watched so far only show how to compile bootstrap.

Comment: Grunt is just another task runner. There's no point using both gulp and grunt. How are the resource files (css/js etc.) being referenced in the template?

Comment: This is how the templates index.html file looks like: http://pastebin.com/bYY73JwE

Comment: Ok, so as you can see from this file, the author is running builds of CSS and JS files. If you are not comfortable with grunt and prefer gulp, I would replicated these builds using Elixer/Gulp as shown above as long as you know what you are doing. The template uses a mix of Laravel and Angular and as I am not an angular head, I wouldn't feel comfortable advising on what views are dependent on what in the template.

Comment: I am so confused i don't even know the right questions to ask,  i am totally new to gulp/grunt/elixir, i have read the docs but never implemented any before.

Comment: I tried mix.vendor() to mix all the files in my vendor folder but that didn't work when i run "gulp --production" it said "TypeError: undefined is not a function"

Comment: the term mix.sass or mix.less are not references to a directory, they are references to a filetype. If you wish to mix a less file in a vendor folder then you need to use mix.less(['vendor/my-less-file.less', 'vendor/my-other-less-file.less']);. If you need to learn more on elixir and laravel, then I would check out laracasts to give you a base. It's probably not the best idea to pick up Laravel from a template, particularly a template that blends another MVC framework into it. You might be better off getting another template as the learning curve here seems to be quite steep.

Comment: Okay i think i may be getting a hang of it, so i use gulp to generate the minified build which i can  run in my browser, then i use elixir's watch to watch the files i make changes to so that it automatically runs gulpjs?

Comment: Can we please have this conversation in the chat? It'll be quick.